# Change style of QML controls at runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I want to change style of QML controls, say, from Material to Universal at runtime (**not** just switch Material Light to Material Dark). What is canonical way to do this? How QML files should be wrote for this? I mean I know about `QQuickStyle::setStyle`; I don't understand which controls I should use and how to deal with them.

**UPD** As I understand it, the only way to change the design style at runtime is to change **all** parameters of **all** elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but only in a "disruptive" way:

> It is not possible to change the style on the fly, because QQC2
> styling is based on QML type registration time file selection, but it
> is possible to:
>
> - unload all QML,
> - destroy any existing QQmlEngine instance(s),
> - call qmlClearTypeRegistrations(),
> - call QQuickStyle::setStyle(),
> - and then re-load the QML content so that QQC2 types are re-registered with the new style.
>
> This process should be clearly documented in QQuickStyle. Preferably,
> an example should be provided that uses QML Settings to retain the
> state of the UI, for example.
>
> It is important to emphasize the warning in the
> qmlClearTypeRegistrations() docs:
>
> > Do not call this function while a QQmlEngine exists or behavior will
> > be undefined. Any existing QQmlEngines must be deleted before calling
> > this function. This function only affects the application global
> > cache. Delete the QQmlEngine to clear all cached data relating to that
> > engine.

[QTBUG-68567: Document how to change the style at run-time](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68567)

The auto tests use this approach to run a series of tests with each built-in style without needing a unique application/project for each one. For example:

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/tests/auto/shared/qtest_quickcontrols.h#n54

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you want, but the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qquickstyle.html#details) for QQuickStyle says this:

> **Note**: The style must be configured before loading QML that imports Qt
> Quick Controls 2. It is not possible to change the style after the QML
> types have been registered.

Comment: Great thanks! This is very disappointing feature of QML.